# How to get device display DPI for API 30+?

Tags: android

Before API 30, you could do this:

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
App.log("ScreenDensity: ${displayMetrics.densityDpi}")
App.log("ScreenDensity: W - ${displayMetrics.xdpi}")
App.log("ScreenDensity: H - ${displayMetrics.ydpi}")
```

But since API 30, `DisplayMetrics` is deprecated and you have to use `WindowMetrics` instead. But I dont see any DPI related functions inside `WindowMetrics`.

Answer (score 1):

While `WindowManager#getDefaultDisplay()` is deprecated, [`DisplayMetrics`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics) itself is not deprecated. You can get an instance like below in Kotlin:

```
 resources.displayMetrics
```

So you can get density like this:

```
 resources.displayMetrics.density
```

Comment: you say you can use Context#getDisplay() but your provided sollution doesn't use that

Comment: @IvoBeckers Thank you. I was confused.